# boto3 - base64 encoded lifecycle configuration produces instance failure

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, binary, base64, boto3

I am trying to set up lifecycle configurations for Sagemaker notebooks over the aws api via boto3. From the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_notebook_instance_lifecycle_config) it reads that a base64 encoded string of the configuration has to be provided.

I am using the following code:

```
with open(lifecycleconfig.sh, 'rb') as fp:
    file_content = fp.read()
config_string = base64.b64encode(file_content).decode('utf-8')
boto3.client('sagemaker').create_notebook_instance_lifecycle_config(
    NotebookInstanceLifecycleConfigName='mylifecycleconfig1',
    OnCreate=[
        {
            'Content': config_string
        },
    ],
)
```

With some `lifecycleconfig.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
```

This creates a lifecycle configuration which shows up in the web interface and whose content is seemingly identical to creating a config by hand: 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yANOP.jpg).

However Notebooks using the lifecycle config created via boto3 will not start and the log file will show error:

```
/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/create_script.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/create_script.sh: line 3: set: -
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
```

Moreover, if I copy paste the content of the corrupted config and create a new config by hand, the new one will now also not start.

**How do I have to encode a bash script for a working aws lifecycle configuration?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it is actually a Windows specific problem concerning the difference between `open(..., 'rb').read()` and `open(..., 'r').read().encode('utf-8')`.

On my linux machine these two give the same result. On Windows however `open(..., 'rb')` gives stuff like `\r\n` for new lines, which appearantly can be comprehended by Amazon's web interface, but not the linux machine where the script gets deployed.

This is a os independent solution:

```
with open(lifecycleconfig.sh, 'r') as fp:
    file_content = fp.read()
config_string = base64.b64encode(file_content.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
```